# Bone selection in weight paint and paint mask enabled

Tags: weight-paint-mode

Good day all!
In previous blender i can select bones in weight paint + paint mask mode enabled, with CTRL+click
In blender 3 i can't do this, it is possible?[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 2.93 and 3.0 to enable this you must select the armature; shift select the mesh; and then enter weight paint mode.  Once you are in weight paint mode, You need to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while left selecting the bone.  I've just verified that this works in 3.0

Comment: Thank for reply! but do u turn on the Paint Mask mode? I cant select in this mode, pls see pict above

Comment: That's how it works in 2.9 as well.  I believe the change was made after 2.83, but I don't know for sure.  3.0 weight paint is almost 100% the same as 2.9x weight paint.

Comment: seems this feature has gone cause new multi selected object edit mode feature, like changed knife project workflow.
I find, that you cant select in mask mode is very annoying behavior, you need to switch on off paint mask every time you want to select second bone.

Comment: and worse there's no easy hot-key way to toggle the paint mask.

Comment: No, there is, you can use <M> or <V> keys, to toggle 'Face Paint' mask or 'Vertex selection' accordingly

Comment: This answer is gold. I don't know why they changed that, it was way simpler in 2.7.